# Unable to start VM instance with Nvidia Tesla K80

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm unable to start a new VM Instance with a Nvidia Tesla K80 GPU.

Whenever I try to start, i get the following error message:

> Start VM instance "gpu-1"
> My First Project
> The zone 'projects/XXX/zones/europe-west1-b' does not have enough resources
> available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again
> later.

I've tried nearly all zones around the world, that have Nvidia Tesla K80 GPUs. I've also tried different hours of the day.

Is it correct, that the rather cheap GPUs are most of the time heavily overbooked all around the world or is it a misleading error message I am receiving? Or is some maintenance going on, I did not notice?

Comment: late here, but might be worth double checking that your region has the GPU model you want: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPUs are resources that are not available in all the zones, you can see the GPUs availables per zone in the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#gpus-list).

Also,  they are a high demanded resources, for this reason sometimes is difficult to create an instance using GPUs,
I tried in my own project and I received the same problem in some zones, but at the end, I was able to create an instance with `nvidia-tesla-k80` using the following command

```
gcloud compute instances create test-instance \
        --zone=us-west1-b \
        --machine-type=n1-standard-1 \
        --image-project=eip-images \
        --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
        --accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1 \
        --image=debian-9-drawfork-v20200207 \
        --boot-disk-size=50GB \
        --boot-disk-type=pd-standard\
```

And I received the following output:

```
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectname/zones/us-west1-b/instances/test-instance].
NAME           ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP   STATUS
test-instance  us-west1-b  n1-standard-1               10.x.x.x   34.x.x.x      RUNNING
```

I hope you find this information useful.